How to deal with square root of negative number when calculating spacetime interval?
I was reading Hartle's Gravity: An Introduction to Einstein's General Relativity and I was doing an exercise from page 57 that asks me to use the metric $\Delta s^2=-(c\Delta t)^2+\Delta x^2$ determine the longest and the shortest side of the triangle ABC drawn on the spacetime diagram below.

I have doubts on how $\Delta s_{BC}$ is calculated. I went with $\Delta s_{BC}=\sqrt{-(c\Delta t_{BC})^2}=\sqrt{-9}$ and I was not sure how to deal with this square root of negative quantity. The answer from the textbook says $\Delta s_{BC}=3$. I am confused how did they do it? Did they change the sign convention from $-+++$ to $+---$ for convenience?

With STEM texts, the titles are almost all the same, and so you should state which authors you mean. For the intervals, compute all the $\Delta s^2$ values, note if they are positive or negative, writing them as time-like or space-like or light-like, and then take the square root of its magnitude.

@naturallyInconsistent So if $Delta s^2$ happens to be negative, then ignore them? I don't get why we should do that.

I never said to ignore that. The sign of $\Delta s^2$ tells you if the interval is time-like, light-like, or space-like. Whatever answer you present, you have to write this down too. Once you are done writing that down, you proceed with just the magnitude; the negative sign will no longer be of use.

This is ugly. I don't know for sure if roots of negative numbers are allowed in relativity theory, but writing $\sqrt {-1}$ is a source of evil and confusion, as $-1=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}=\sqrt{1}=1$. You should at least use a proper complex notation using the well defined imaginary unit $i$ instead of the error prone $\sqrt{-1}$.

$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_hyperbola  asymptotes as a cone of light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone ..., $R^{2}=\pm 1$ radius of circles in the Minkowski sense.

For a non-lightlike 4-vector,
write $\tilde S=S \hat S$, where $\hat S$ is the unit 4-vector along $\tilde S$.

(You could use $\Delta \tilde s$, but I am trying to minimize the notational clutter.)
How do we calculate $S$?
\begin{align}
\tilde S \cdot \tilde S 
&= (S \hat S) \cdot (S \hat S)\\
&= S^2 (\hat S \cdot \hat S)\\
\frac{\tilde S\cdot \tilde S}{(\hat S \cdot \hat S)}&= S^2 \\
\end{align}
So, $$S=\sqrt{\frac{\tilde S\cdot \tilde S}{(\hat S \cdot \hat S)}}
=\sqrt{\left|\tilde S\cdot \tilde S\right|}
$$
Note:
when $\tilde S \cdot \tilde S>0$, then $\hat S \cdot \hat S=+1$.
when $\tilde S \cdot \tilde S<0$, then $\hat S \cdot \hat S=-1$.
So, in both the timelike and spacelike cases, the argument is positive.
This amounts to identifying the type of interval (timelike or spacelike),
then taking the square-root of the magnitude of the square-interval to find the component of $\tilde S$ along $\hat S$.

If the question is merely which side of the triangle ABC is the longest, the answer is always AB because BC is always negative (since it extends into the time direction), whereas the the square of AB is added.

I prefer the $c\Delta \tau =\sqrt{ c^2\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 }$ convention. With this notation  $\Delta \tau$ has a quite literal physical interpretation as the proper time on a clock transported from event $(t_1, x_1)$ to event $(t_2, x_2)$. Using units such c = 1 and if we have two events such that $(t_1, x_1) = (0,0)$ and $(t_2, x_2) =( 0,3)$ then the spacetime interval is $c\Delta \tau =\sqrt{ c^2\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 } = \sqrt{ -9 } = 3 i $. This tells us that the proper time on a clock transported between those two events is imaginary and therefore the interval is not a time interval. It turns out that the equivalent real spatial distance between the two events is equal to $ i c\Delta \tau $. It's one intuitive way of viewing the spacetime interval.
In Newtonian physics we have $\Delta t = \Delta x/v$ which is the time interval for a particle moving a distance $\Delta x$ at velocity v. The spatial distance is $\Delta x = v \Delta t$. We have one equation to calculate the time and another to calculate the distance. Similarly in the relativistic case we can use $\Delta \tau =\sqrt{ \Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2/c^2 }$ to calculate the proper time interval and $\Delta s =\sqrt{ \Delta x^2 - c^2 \Delta t^2 } \ $ to calculate the proper distance between the events.
